# Why is Logitech USB Receiver using too much power?

Tags: usb, power-management, battery, logitech

I upgraded to Kubuntu 19.10 today. To get the most battery out of my machine, I installed and calibrated tlp.
When I inspect power usages, I can see logitech usb sucks too much power.
Here's a screenshot from my powertop application:

[image: powertop]

Is this normal? Can I do anything to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port I plugged USB receiver was the one which supports charging. Moving the USB to the other port lowered power usage by 10 fold.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience. incidentally, I was investigating the power draw of the USB receiver because the KVM at work is very picky and now I can use it without worry.

Answer (score 1):

The power usage of a USB device is not likely to change because it was moved to a different port.  What is far more likely is that the reporting of the power consumption changed by moving to a new port.  A charging USB port will have to make a larger power budget allocation if anything is detected on the port as a device that is charging from USB doesn't always ask nicely for power like other USB devices would.  The power use is an estimate, and is likely erring on the side of reporting maximum possible power draw than leave a large consumer of power go unnoticed.

One should be aware that there's no actual measurement of power draw from the USB port, the computer only knows how much power the devices requested.  Whether the devices use all the power they request, or take more than they requested, is left unknown.  The computer is left to trust the power reporting from USB devices, at least up to the point the devices trip an over current protection device.

Some devices will have the means to report actual power use, like a battery management system in a laptop.  This ability to accurately report power use is more the exception than the rule.  Other parts of the computer may have a power budget system like USB does and those too will only report power consumed as estimates based on what the device reports, not based on an actual measurement.

Comment: I could reproduce the increase of power usage whenever I used that port with the same receiver. Sadly I don't have a third USB port so I could test more. Still, thanks for the insight.

Comment: It's unlikely the actual power usage increases as 3 watts into a tiny (I assume) RF mouse receiver would make it quite hot to the touch.  I believe the issue is that the non-charging port is using a micrometer to measure power draw and the charging port is using a yardstick to measure power draw.  The accuracy of the measurement is the issue I'm seeing, not actual changes in power consumed.  Getting a USB power meter should show this.